# Function call with template parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, overloading

I have written a simple class template:

```
template <class T>
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class(T value)
        : my_Value(value)
    {
    }
private:
    T my_Value;
};
```

Now I can use this template in a simple function signature like: `my_function(my_class<std::string> my_string)`

When I want to call the function I can easily use it:

```
auto my_instance = my_class<std::string>("my value");
my_function(my_instance);
```

But what I want to realize is a function call like this:

```
my_function("my value")
```

My class template should implicit do the conversion to the type of the template for me. I think I need some kind of operator overload.

`std:optional` can do this for example.

Comment: There are several options, add another constructor for `my_class`, add overload for `my_function`, change call site to call it with `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have only one implicit user-conversion, so your call with `const char*` is invalid.

There are several options,

- add another constructor for my_class

  ```
  my_class(T value) : my_Value(value) {}

  template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>, int> = 0>
  my_class(U value) : my_Value(value) {}
  ```
- add overload for my_function,

  ```
  void my_function(my_class<std::string> my_string)
  void my_function(const char* s) { return my_function(my_class<std::string>{s}); }
  ```
- change call site to call it with `std::string`:

  ```
  my_function(std::string("my value"))

  using namespace std::string_literals;
  my_function("my value"s)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add constructor accepting type convertible to your `T`.

The "classic" pre-C++20 way is to use SFINAE and `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class
{
public:
   template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T,U>>>
   my_class(U&& arg) : my_Value(std::forward<U>(arg)) 
   {}

...
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nxz13K)

---

With newest standard (C++20) you can use concepts and simplify your code:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class
{
public:
   template <typename U>
   my_class(U&& arg) requires(std::is_constructible_v<T,U>) 
      : my_Value(std::forward<U>(arg)) 
   {}

...
```

Or even simpler:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
concept constructible_to = std::constructible_from<U, T>;

template <typename T>
class my_class
{
public:
   template <constructible_to<T> U>
   my_class(U&& arg)
      : my_Value(std::forward<U>(arg)) 
   {}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained already, your problem is that you want to have two implicit conversions in a row (string literal (`char const*`) => `std::string` => `my_class<std::string>`) while only one is allowed.

Several ways how to reduce this chain to one have been explained already, but there is one more: Simply pass a `std::string` directly to your function instead of a string literal

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
my_function("my value"s);
```

Note the `s` which creates a `std::string` from a string literal. You need to use that namespace to have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is described here:

[Implicit conversions - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

> #### Order of the conversions
>
> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one *standard conversion sequence*;
> 2. zero or one *user-defined conversion*;
> 3. zero or one *standard conversion sequence*.
>
> When considering the argument to a constructor or to a user-defined conversion function, only a standard conversion sequence is allowed (otherwise user-defined conversions could be effectively chained). When converting from one built-in type to another built-in type, only a standard conversion sequence is allowed.

Your current code requires chain of two implicit user defined conversions: form  `const char *` to `std::string` and then from `std::string` to `my_class<std::string>`.

To solve this you have to reduce this chain. So basically you need to provide constructor which will allow conversion of string literal to your `my_class<std::string>`.

`PiotrNycz` has provide solution:

```cpp
template <class T>
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class(const T& value)
        : my_Value(value)
    {
    }

   template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T,U>>>
   my_class(U&& arg) : my_Value(std::forward<U>(arg)) 
   {}

private:
    T my_Value;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPezMb)